# How to prevent mongoid has_many from firing a query on a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two classes, A and B

```
class A
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :bs, class_name: "B"
end

class B
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :a
end
```

In the rails console, i type:

```
a = A.new
```

and it returns

```
=> #<A _id: 5dab1f7780256231d1bb6da8, >
```

Great, it's a new record, so i know a priori, that there are no b's, yet when I type:

```
a.bs
```

It fires off a mongo query:

```
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.867215 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.875124 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server localhost:27017 initializing.
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.878528 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' changed to type 'single'.
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.879335 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'unknown' to 'standalone'.
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.880055 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'single' topology.
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.881797 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"bs", "filter"=>{"a_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5dab1f7780256231d1bb6da8')}}
D, [2019-10-19T10:36:41.884234 #12753] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | test_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001728129s
```

This is maddening, is there any way to prevent this?  I'm doing this for millions of records, and it's firing all these unneeded queries.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There is a use case for the behavior you are experiencing:

```
class A
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :bs, class_name: "B"
end

class B
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :a
end

a = A.create!(id: 1, bs: [B.new])
a.destroy
aa = A.new(id: 1)
aa.bs
# => [#<B _id: 5dacc787026d7c52b820f0c1, a_id: 1>]
```

You will most likely need to adjust your code to not query the association if you don't want it loaded. For example, if you are creating B instances, use `B.new` supplying the A rather than going through `A.bs`.

Comment: But that doesn't really help me though b/c the goal is have no queries until they need them.  Mongoid should know that bs must be empty, b/c a i a new record.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity. `aa` is a new record and has bs.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid actually *can't* know that there are no B's associated with your new A instance because B is storing the foreign key to A, not the other way around. (See the [Mongoid Belongs To documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#belongs-to).) It sounds like your schema isn't set up in the way you need it to be to perform these queries efficiently.

You could add an index on the `a_id` field in the B schema, which would make those queries faster, or you could rework your schema so that the foreign key is stored on the A model somehow.

Comment: so is this a design flaw with mongoid?  Mongoid knows that at time t=0 that a is a new_record?  So with this knowledge, it cannot be the case that a has any b's.

Comment: I don't think this is a design flaw with Mongoid. When you run `a.bs`, what you're essentially doing is: 

`B.find_by(a_id: a.id)`

Even though `a` is a new record at t=0, that does not guarantee that there aren't any `B`s that have `a`'s id in their `a_id` field. Consider the example @DSM posted above -- even though `aa` is a new document, there exists a `B` that has `a_id:1`.